# Tricks to override plot.factor?

Tags: r, plot

I've been using `plot` for quite awhile now and I'm wondering how much would be broken if the type argument could override categorical predictors.  Right now plot always attempts boxplots when the x variable is a factor.  It seems that the `plot.factor` method always gets called then.  It would be nice if type could override that feature and I didn't have to make the x-axis numerical, suppress it, and then add it later.  I'm not interested in a wrapper function since I've pretty much just described how to do that.  I'm just wondering if there's a `plot` argument I've missed that can solve this.

For example, typically a boxplot is attempted in this case...

```
y <- 1:4
x <- factor(letters[1:4])
plot(y ~ x)
```

I'd prefer it to just plot the points and label the x-axes correctly.  The following works but I was hoping for a simpler version.

```
nx <- length(x)
plot(y ~ 1:nx, xaxt = 'n')
axis(1, 1:nx, x, xlab = '')
```

I was hoping something like the following might work...

```
plot(y ~ x, type = 'n')
points(1:nx, y)
```

but no go.  And `type = 'p'` doesn't do it either.

I believe this last failure is yet another example of inconsistency in R.  Setting `type = 'n'` should be working in method calls as well or it should be mandatory that all `plot` functions use it (inherited or at least passed through `...`).  It's in `plot.default`.

Comment: FYI: The behavior of the `type` argument you label a bug is in fact the documented behavior. When describing further arguments in `plot.factor` the documentation clearly says "None accept type.". What you describe would be more like a feature request, that R Core add a type argument to `boxplot` (which is what is eventually called). And they would probably (rightly) argue that it's not really worth the effort to save people the 1-2 extra lines of calling `axis`.

Comment: I think there's something to be said for consistency even moreso than conciseness.  OK, yes, perhaps I should put it in as a feature request.

Comment: Hey, I'm actually on your side here. I think that tracking down which arguments go with which methods for a generic like `plot` can be more complex than one would ideally hope. I was just pointing out the (somewhat banal) fact that this very complexity mean making changes can be much more work than the benefits.

Comment: might it work to write your own `Plot()` command that implemented the desired behavio(u)rs?

Answer (score 4):

You could just call plot.default:

```
y<-rnorm(100)
x<-factor(sample(c("a","b","c"),size=100,replace=TRUE))
plot.default(x,y)
```

edit: Changed factor levels to characters so it is clear that this works even then.

Comment: +1 That's good but you still have to suppress the x-axis and then put it back on.  It doesn't save any steps but it better expresses intent in the code than the way I was doing it.

Comment: Okay now that you updated your question I understand what you are looking for. Yes this doesn't help in the x-axis. As x is factor using generic plot function will always use plot.factor method, and with numeric y that will result a boxplot. IF there is a more clever way of doing this than suppressing and redoing x-axis, I guess it still needs plot.default.